# How would I go about using a drop down list using a select query to update text fields based on selected option (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

Example:

```
echo '<select>';
$mysqli = new mysqli( "localhost", "root", "user", "db" );
$con = $mysqli;
if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) {
die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);    
}
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$selectStatement = "SELECT id FROM purchase_order WHERE username = ?";  
$statement1 = $mysqli->prepare( $selectStatement );
$statement1->bind_param( "s", $username );
$statement1->execute();
$statement1->bind_result( $id );
while( $statement1->fetch() ) {                         
echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $id . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Now lets say I have text fields for Quantity, Description, Amount, Subtotal, Tax, Total and once I select ID 2 in the drop down list, I'd like for the values in the text fields to show the data of the 2nd ID in my database.

```
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM purchase_order WHERE username = ?";   
$statement1 = $mysqli->prepare( $selectStatement );
$statement1->bind_param( "s", $username );
$statement1->execute();
$statement1->bind_result( $id );
$statement1->fetch();

echo '<input type="text" value="' . $quantity . '" id="quantity" name="quantity" readonly>';

echo '<input type="text" value="' . $description . '" id="description" name="description" readonly>';

echo '<input type="text" value="' . $amount . '" id="amount" name="amount" readonly>';

etc.
```

I assume its a $_GET or $_POST solution. I'm not sure how to approach this. Please help.

Comment: If you want this to happen without submitting the form, you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to the `<select>`, so you can refer to it when the form is submitted.

Then use this POST parameter to look up the details of that row of the table.

```
echo '<form method="POST">';
echo '<select name="po_id">';
$mysqli = new mysqli( "localhost", "root", "user", "db" );
$con = $mysqli;
if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);    
}
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$selectStatement = "SELECT id FROM purchase_order WHERE username = ?";  
$statement1 = $mysqli->prepare( $selectStatement );
$statement1->bind_param( "s", $username );
$statement1->execute();
$statement1->bind_result( $id );
while( $statement1->fetch() ) {                         
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $id . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

if (isset($_POST['po_id'])) {

    $username = $_SESSION['user'];
    $selectStatement = "SELECT quantity, description, amount FROM purchase_order WHERE username = ? AND id = ?";
    $statement1 = $mysqli->prepare( $selectStatement );
    $statement1->bind_param( "si", $username, $_POST['po_id'] );
    $statement1->execute();
    $statement1->bind_result( $quantity, $description, $amount );
    $statement1->fetch();

    echo '<input type="text" value="' . $quantity . '" id="quantity" name="quantity" readonly>';
    echo '<input type="text" value="' . $description . '" id="description" name="description" readonly>';
    echo '<input type="text" value="' . $amount . '" id="amount" name="amount" readonly>';
}
echo '</form>';
```

If you want to do this without submitting the form, you'll need to learn JavaScript and AJAX. That's more than I'm willing to teach in this answer.